# Django Multiple table to authentication

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'd like to have 3 differents table and use them to authenticate.

The Contact will authenticate himself with his phone number, ChainStore with his identifier and User (django user admin) will have his normal behavior (with username). ChainStore and Contact have forms to authenticate, how can i do ?

Here is my models:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.ForeignKey(
        Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True
    )
    email = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=140)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    optin_email = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    optin_sms = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
class ChainStore(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    rules = models.JSONField(default=dict)
```

I've tried to use inheritance with AbstractBaseUser but i had problems like

> auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Contact.groups'

My Forms:

```
class ContactSignUp(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    mobile = forms.RegexField(max_length=12)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=32)
    password_verification = forms.CharField(max_length=32)

class ContactAuth(forms.Form):
    mobile = forms.CharField(max_length=12)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=32)
```

My views:

```
class ContactSignUpView(FormView):
    form_class = ContactSignUp
    model = Contact
    template_name = "sign_up.html"
    success_url = "/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed."""
        Contact(
            first_name=form.cleaned_data["first_name"],
            last_name=form.cleaned_data["last_name"],
            email=form.cleaned_data["email"],
            mobile=form.cleaned_data["mobile"],
            password=form.cleaned_data["password"]
        ).save()
        return super().form_valid(form)


class ContactAuthView(FormView):
    form_class = forms.ContactAuth
    model = Contact
    template_name = "auth.html"
    success_url = "/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed."""
        user = ContactBackend().authenticate(
            form.cleaned_data["mobile"],
            form.cleaned_data["password"],
        )
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

My backend:

```
class ContactBackend(BaseBackend):
    """
    Mobile Authentication Backend

    Allows a user to sign in using an mobile/password pair rather than
    a username/password pair.
    """
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            contact = models.Contact.objects.get(mobile=username)
            if check_password(password, contact.password): # Imported from django.contrib.auth.hashers
                return contact
        except models.Contact.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return models.Contact.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except models.Contact.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

And finally my settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "auth.User"

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "contact.backends.ContactBackend"
]
```

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: "I'd like to have 3 differents table and use them to authenticate" so how can i do ?